# Images in Blobstore: inefficient to get metadata?

Tags: image, google-app-engine, blobstore

**Summary:** I'm using Blobstore to let users upload images to be served. I want to prevent users from uploading files that aren't valid images or have dimensions that are too large. I'm using App Engine's Images service to get the relevant metadata. BUT, in order to get any information about the image type or dimensions from the Images service, you have to first execute a transform, which fetches the transformed image to the App Engine server. I have it do a no-op crop and encode as a very low quality JPEG image, but it's still fetching an actual image, and all I want is the dimensions and file type. Is this the best I can do? Will the internal transfer of the image data (from Blobstore to App Engine server) cost me?

**Details:**

It seems like Blobstore was carefully designed for efficient serving of images from App Engine. On the other hand, certain operations seem to make you jump through inefficient hoops. I'm hoping someone can tell me that there's a more efficient way, or convince me that what I'm doing is not as wasteful as I think it is.

I'm letting users upload images to be served as part of other user-generated content. Blobstore makes the uploading and serving pretty easy. Unfortunately it lets the user upload any file they want, and I want to impose restrictions.

(Side note: Blobstore does let you limit the file size of uploads, but this feature is poorly documented. It turns out that if the user tries to exceed the limit, Blobstore will return a 413 "Entity too large", and the App Engine handler is not called at all.)

I want to allow only valid JPEG, GIF, and PNG files, and I want to limit the dimensions. The way to do this seems to be to check the file after upload, and delete it if it's not allowed. Here's what I've got:

```
class ImageUploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
  def post(self):
    try:
      # TODO: Check that user is logged in and has quota; xsrfToken.
      uploads = self.get_uploads()
      if len(uploads) != 1:
        logging.error('{} files uploaded'.format(len(uploads)))
        raise ServerError('Must be exactly 1 image per upload')
      image = images.Image(blob_key=uploads[0].key())
      # Do a no-op transformation; otherwise execute_transforms()
      # doesn't work and you can't get any image metadata.
      image.crop(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)
      image.execute_transforms(output_encoding=images.JPEG, quality=1)
      if image.width > 640 or image.height > 640:
        raise ServerError('Image must be 640x640 or smaller')
      resultUrl = images.get_serving_url(uploads[0].key())
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
      self.response.body = jsonEncode({'status': 0, 'imageUrl': resultUrl})
    except Exception as e:
      for upload in uploads:
        blobstore.delete(upload.key()) # TODO: delete in parallel with delete_async
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
      self.response.status = 403
      self.response.body = e.args[0]
```

Comments in the code highlight the issue.

I know the image can be resized on the fly at serve time (using get_serving_url), but I'd rather force users to upload a smaller image in the first place, to avoid using up storage. Later, instead of putting a limit on the original image dimensions, I might want to have it automatically get shrunk at upload time, but I'd still need to find out its dimensions and type before shrinking it.

Am I missing an easier or more efficient way?

Comment: have you seen get_serving_url? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.images?csw=1 might solve some of the resizing problems etc.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood Yes, if you look carefully, I'm using get_serving_url in the above code. It doesn't solve the problems I'm asking about.

Comment: so you are. too much to look through in detail, remove everything that's not relevant to the question perhaps?  Have you considered doing it on the client side? Do you trust your users? I'm not sure what you are really asking. If you want to check if something is really an image, you have to do something like that. You can also inspect the first few bytes of the data to see if it might be an image: https://docs.python.org/2/library/imghdr.html

Comment: I believe it's pretty much all relevant, but you're right that the question is a lot to digest. I will reorganize to highlight the central points.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood, I moved the most important stuff to the top and removed 3 lines of misguided code, plus a bit of question text. Users are NOT trusted in general. I don't believe a client-side check would provide the level of security that I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the Blobstore is not exactly optimized for serving images, it operates on any kind of data. [The BlobReader class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_BlobReader) can be used to manage the raw blob data.

[The GAE Images service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/) can be used to manage images (including those stored as blobs in the BlobStore). You are right in the sense that this service only offers info about the uploaded image only *after* executing a transformation on it, which doesn't help with deleting undesirable blob images prior to processing.

What you can do is use [the Image module from the PIL library](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm) (available between the [GAE's Runtime-Provided Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27?hl=en#runtime-libraries)) overlayed on top of the BlobReader class.

The PIL Image `format` and `size` methods to get the info you seek and sanitize the image data before reading the entire image:

```
>>> image = Image.open('Spain-rail-map.jpg')
>>> image.format
'JPEG'
>>> image.size
(410, 317)
```

These methods should be very efficient since they only need image header info from the blob loaded by the `open` method:

> Opens and identifies the given image file. This is a lazy operation;
>   the function reads the file header, but the actual image data is not
>   read from the file until you try to process the data (call the **load**
>   method to force loading).

This is how overlaying can be done in your `ImageUploadHandler`:

```
  from PIL import Image
  with blobstore.BlobReader(uploads[0].key()) as fd:
      image = Image.open(fd)
      logging.error('format=%s' % image.format)
      logging.error('size=%dx%d' % image.size)
```

Comment: Ok, I think I like this pretty well. Presumably instead of a file name, you can call `Image.open` on the BlobReader. Then it will only read as much data from the blob as it needs (well, rounded up to a multiple of the buffer size; I guess the optimal buffer size is probably small).

Comment: One thing this won't do, that my code above does do, is validate the entire image file. To do that with a PIL Image and BlobReader, it would have to fetch the entire blob, which uses a lot more bandwidth than fetching a transformed low-quality JPEG.

Comment: I'm just sort of surprised that Blobstore doesn't provide a way to fetch the metadata without the (transformed) image data. I would think this would be in Google's interest, since (as far as I can tell) they won't be charging me for it (still not sure if this is true).

Comment: I may need to update my answer as I see no `size` method in the implementation: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/api/images

Comment: That's the Image class from the App Engine Images service, entirely separate from the PIL Image class. I think your answer is still correct. (Haven't tried it though.)

Answer (score 1):

When you upload to Google Cloud Storage (GCS) instead of the blobstore you have much more control over object upload conditions like name, type and size. A policy document controls the user conditions. If the user does not meet these upload conditions, the object will be rejected.

Docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object#policydocument).

Example:

```
{"expiration": "2010-06-16T11:11:11Z",
 "conditions": [
  ["starts-with", "$key", "" ],
  {"acl": "bucket-owner-read" },
  {"bucket": "travel-maps"},
  {"success_action_redirect":"http://www.example.com/success_notification.html" },
  ["eq", "$Content-Type", "image/jpeg" ],
  ["content-length-range", 0, 1000000]
  ]
}
```

The POST response if the content length was exceeded:

```
<Error>
    <Code>EntityTooLarge</Code>
    <Message>
        Your proposed upload exceeds the maximum allowed object size.
    </Message>
    <Details>Content-length exceeds upper bound on range</Details>
</Error>
```

The POST response if a PDF was send:

```
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidPolicyDocument</Code>
    <Message>
        The content of the form does not meet the conditions specified in the policy document.
    </Message>
    <Details>Policy did not reference these fields: filename</Details>
</Error>
```

And [here](https://github.com/voscausa/appengine-gcs-upload) you can find my Python code for a direct upload to GCS.

Comment: Yeah, I'd been wondering about GCS too, although I'm not sure it makes much difference in my case. It doesn't look like it would parse the image file on upload and be able to reject it based on dimensions or invalid file contents, would it? The docs don't seem to mention that. I'm pretty sure putting restrictions on file type just checks the Content-Type header, not the actual file contents. I might switch to GCS later to take advantage of user access controls, though.

Comment: I have updated my answer. GCS checks the content length in the above example. The content type is saved as GCS meta data, but not checked.

Comment: Not checked. You can send a png with Content Type image/png. But if you send a PDF GCS will return an error.

Comment: @voscausa I notice that when using a policy _without_ any ContentType restrictions, some file extensions are rejected: .jpg can be uploaded, but .jpeg cannot (nor can .pdf).  Do you know if GCS has restrictions on what kinds of files can be uploaded?

Comment: Create a new question. I have no answer for you.