# Limit upload size for appengine interface to cloud store

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Consider an image (avatar) uploader to Google Cloud Storage which will start from the user's web browser, and then pass through a Go appengine instance which will handle standard compression/cropping etc. and then set the resulting image as an object in Cloud Storage

How can I ensure that the appengine instance isn't overloaded by too much or bad data? In other words, I think I'm asking two questions (or possibly not):

1. How can I limit the amount of data allowed to be sent to an appengine instance in a single request, or is there already a default safe limit?
2. How can I validate the data to make sure it's proper jpg/png/gif before attempting to process it with standard go image libraries?

Comment: FWIW (at least in python) if using the Blobstore API (which can work w/ GCS) it's possible to limit upload sizes and with the PIL lib is possible to check the image size/format before processing the whole image (to limit processing costs). The GAE Image API can resize the uploaded images (already limited in filesize) to acceptable images sizes/formats which can be stored in GCS for later use while deleting the uploaded images - saving on storage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33875366/. But I'm not familiar with `go`, can't tell if it supports such approach.

Comment: You should use the blobstore API as @Dan has said.  And when you create an UploadURL you can set a maximum upload size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. All App Engine requests are limited to 32MB.
2. You can check the size of the file being uploaded before the upload starts.
3. You can [verify the file's mime-type](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#DetectContentType) and only allow correct files to be uploaded.

Comment: Actually, you can do more than just check the file extension.
Have a look at https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#DetectContentType.